# Map snapshot in WidgetKit does not call the completionHandler callback of `MKMapSnapshotter.start`

Tags: widget, widgetkit

I've tried `MKMapSnapshotter` in the `TimelineProvider` , but the completion handler of the `start` is never called (`snapshot` is a `MKMapSnapshotter` object and I have verified that the callback is called when this code runs on the actual app and not the widget `TimelineProvider`. What am I missing?

```
    snapshot.start { (snapshot, error) in
      let image = snapshot?.image // Image(uiImage: snapshot?.image)
      completionHandler(image)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some info can be found here :

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653198?page=1#650476022